# How to debug javascript in VS Code in a cakephp project running on xampp?

Tags: javascript, debugging, cakephp, xampp, vscode-debugger

I need help on how to configure vscode to debug javascript code that is already running on chrome.

Here is my launch.json config file:

```
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
    {
        "name": "Listen for XDebug",
        "type": "php",
        "request": "launch",
        "port": 9000
    },
    {
        "name": "Listen for JS Debug",
        "type": "pwa-chrome",
        "request": "attach",
        "port": 9222,
        "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}"
    }
],
```

I'm lauching chrome with `--remote-debugging-port=9222` args and when i click the green arrow to debug the javascript, it starts but doens't stop at breakpoints on the file i'm working at.

Also, i want to show you this image:
[image: breakpoints]

The first breakpoint that you see is set on the file i'm working and it doesn't work.

The second breakpoint actually works, but it only appears if i set a breakpoint in chrome at the "Sources" tab of devtools, and it also creates on vscode a new tab of the file i'm working at but i hover the tab it show that localhost path that you can see.

Some additional info:

- its a cakephp project
- running on xampp (Apache)
- the files are located at C:\xampp\htdocs\ppcr
- xDebug is running well for php debugging

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: why don't you use the Dev Tools for debugging JS?

Comment: @Aris i do use dev tools, because i can't get this "debug on vs code" thing to work. It would be much better to just be able to put a breakpoint that i'm currently working on vs code than open dev tools, search for the file, got to the line and debug, go back to vs code, change the file and save, etc.